# The quantity of wine in each vessel

Tags: algebra-precalculus

A vessel contains $x$ gallons of wine and another contains $y$ gallons of water. From each vessel $z$ gallons are taken out and transferred to the other. From the  resulting mixture in each vessel, $z$ gallons are taken out and transferred to the other. If after the second transfer, the quantity of wine in each vessel remains the same as it was after the first transfer, then show that $z(x+y) = xy$ .

Answer (score 3):

After the first transfer the first vessel contains $x-z$ wine, and the second contains $z$ wine. After the second transfer the first vessel contains $x-z-\dfrac{x-z}{x}z+\dfrac{z}{y}z$ of wine and the second contains $z-\dfrac{z}{y}z+\dfrac{x-z}{x}z$ of wine. Hence we must have $\dfrac{x-z}{x}z=\dfrac{z}{y}z$ or $xy=(x+y)z$.

Comment: how did u get the quantities for the second transfer? @almagest

Comment: @matrikashukla You are assuming the wine is well-mixed after the first transfer. The first vessel contains $x-z$ of wine and $z$ of water after the first transfer. Hence when you remove a total quantity $z$ in the second transfer, the amount of wine removed will be $\frac{x-z}{x}z$.

Comment: why did u add (x/y)z in the first vessel and subtracted (z/y)z in the second vessel??

Comment: @matrikashukla I didn't add $\frac{x}{y}z$ to the first vessel. I subtracted $\frac{z}{y}z$ from the second vessel because we took out a total of $z$, of which a fraction $\frac{z}{y}$ was wine.

Comment: ok .......... I got it now! thank u so much @almagest

Comment: I had already upvoted. I was just wondering whether a non-algebraic rationale can be found for $z/x = y/(x+y)$

Comment: @trueblueanil After the first transfer the wine/water in the first vessel is $1-\frac{z}{x}$ and in the second vessel is $\frac{z}{y}$. You want these to be equal. But I guess that is still fairly algebraic.